# Converting to PDF

Tags: html, forms, pdf, button

I don't know whether this question has been asked/answered. I am making an online form website thing for a school project. I have to try and have a button that converts the filled out form to PDF. Do I need to download some software to do this or can it be done with code. From what I have seen from searching it up it seems like some high level programming. If it can be done with code, what is the code?

Comment: Looks like you're looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412224/how-do-i-output-html-form-data-to-pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print whole page

Try adding a button that calls window.print()

```
<input type="button" value="Print this page" onClick="window.print()">
Print a specific portion/container in a page

<div id="print-content">
 <form>

  <input type="button" onclick="printDiv('print-content')" value="print a div!"/>
</form>
</div>
```

then in HTML file add this script code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printDiv(divName) {
        var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
        w=window.open();
        w.document.write(printContents);
        w.print();
        w.close();
    }
```